# Can an Index be used to restrict which partitions are read in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a column that identifies each run of my ETL-Workflow (let's call it RUN_ID), that I would like to partition on. However, since that will create lots of partitions over time, and partitions can't span multiple values of the partition column, I am wondering whether having a technical column for the sole purpose of partitioning (let's call it PARTITION_ID) would help me here, since then I could merge two partitions without changing RUN_ID.

My question now is, since each RUN_ID can only live in one partition, will indexing on RUN_ID still provide the benefit of not reading all partitions when doing a query with WHERE RUN_ID = xxx or joining on RUN_ID but not providing a PARTITION_ID in the query?

Assume hive 2.1.1

Comment: How many runs do you have per day?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz We are talking about a port of a DW-Framework here, so I can't really make assumptions as to how many there would be; however, in the current DW-Project i am in, there are potentially 10-20 runs for one of the tables per day. I would expect a DW running on Hive to have at least that, if not more.